# Example for using iOS 15's new ConfigurationUpdateHandler for a UIButton in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to try out the new UIButtonConfigurationUpdateHandler that's available in iOS 15 to create a toggle button. There are lots of very nice examples using Swift ([like this one by Sarunw](https://sarunw.com/posts/dynamic-button-configuration/), but most of my codebase is Objective-C. Can someone provide example code on how to dynamically configure a button for me? Thanks!

Comment: *"to create a toggle button"* ??? What do you mean? To get help, please take a few minutes to provide ***details** about what you're trying to do, including images if that would help. Certainly you aren't expecting someone to go through that entire blog post and convert all of the Swift code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will get you on your way...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BtnCfgViewController : UIViewController
{
    BOOL bIsOn;
}
@end

@implementation BtnCfgViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    bIsOn = NO;
    
    if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
        
        UIAction *tapAction = [UIAction actionWithHandler:^(UIAction* action){
            self->bIsOn = !self->bIsOn;
        }];
        
        UIButtonConfiguration *cfg = [UIButtonConfiguration plainButtonConfiguration];
        
        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithConfiguration:cfg
                                                 primaryAction:tapAction];
        
        myButton.configurationUpdateHandler = ^(UIButton *btn) {
            UIButtonConfiguration *cfg = btn.configuration;
            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Toggle: %@", self->bIsOn ? @"☑︎" : @"☐"];
            cfg.title = s;
            btn.configuration = cfg;
        };
        
        myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
        
        UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
        
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
            
            [myButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:20.0],
            [myButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:200.0],
            [myButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60.0],
            [myButton.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor],
            
        ]];
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed... sorry if I wasn't clear. In the end, the `btn.configuration = cfg;` line was what I was missing.